# wordpress redirect to login form

Tags: php, wordpress

I know that are some answers to my question but i don't know if my problem exists in the other persons who asked for help.

I have this function that helps me to redirect users to login before access any contetnt of my website:

```
    function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        wp_safe_redirect(wp_login_url(get_permalink()));
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

That function works fine but i have a problem. When somebody is navigated to my home page and click to a link that goes here: 'example.com/about' then my function works great. When somebody he trying to go direct to 'example.com/about' by entering this into browser url then my function doesn't work and he is able to access my website. What i have do wrong? I have write my function in my templates function.php file.

I just created a page template called restriction_page.php:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Restricted Page
*/
?>

<h1>Hello There</h1>

<?php
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && !is_home()){
        wp_safe_redirect(wp_login_url());
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
 ?>
```

i set this template as the fefault template in my about page. No solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method :1** 
you can add it to the top of page.php

If you want to add more pages, just add the ||(or) operator like so:

```
<?php
$pageTitle == get_the_title();
  if($pageTitle == 'Submit' || $pageTitle =='NewPage') {
       if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
         redirect code
     } else {
         page code
     }
  } else {
  page code
}
?>
```

**Method:2**

Write this into a plugin:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'auth_redirect' );
```

This will force all visitors login if they aren’t already.

In some cases, this is asking for a log-in every time. This might work better:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    is_user_logged_in() || auth_redirect();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built in [**`auth_redirect()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/auth_redirect) function for this:

```
function restrict_access_if_logged_out(){

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ){
        auth_redirect();
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'restrict_access_if_logged_out', 3 );
```

**Note:** This should go in your themes *functions.php* file

Answer (score 0):

You should create a template page for restricted page like we create full width page tamplate, right sidebar page template, left sidebar template, etc. And in restricted page template call your function. When going to create pages, choose restricted template from the listed of the page template in right side.

If it doesn't help you, we'll be able to help you, when you paste your more code with more detail.

Comment: i did it. I created a page template called restrictes_page.php, i inserted my php function and i went to about page and set as template the page template i created..but no solution..